# Ember-Cli import plugin without bower

Tags: import, bower, ember-cli, pnotify

I need to import in my ember-cli project some GitHub plugins like PNotify and Ember-suggest. 
Bower does not find them or, in the specific case of Pnotify, when I try to execute the command 'ember server' it says that PNotify is not defined.

Is there a way to import plugins without using bower or npm manager?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find the 'ember way' to do this?

Comment: yes, you have to install PNotify with bower. Open the terminal and run: bower install --save pnotify; after that open Brocfile.js and import Pnotify in this manner: app.import('vendor/pnotify/pnotify.css'); app.import('vendor/pnotify/pnotify.js'); At last open the .jshintrc file and into 'predef' write "PNotify": true

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out as well for non-bower plugins and submitted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current ember-cli >= 0.0.42 there is a difference between the bower_components directory and the vendor directory. bower_components is ignored by default in the included .gitignore and should be where bower installs and updates standard components. vendor is for any strange one-off libraries that are not in the bower lookup, and *will* be checked in unless you add /vendor to your .gitignore

If you want to import libraries that do NOT use Bower, for example `myscroller.js`, you should:

1. Create a sub-directory in the vendor directory and manually copy your file. `/vendor/myscroller/myscroller.js`
2. Add this to your Brocfile `app.import('vendor/myscroller/myscroller.js');`
3. Add any global mehtods used by the library to the .jshintrc file. Do this by adding the name of the constant as true to the 'predef' section. `"MyScroller": true,`

Now you can use your library anywhere as normal.